# How to store ResultSet in an array of object

Tags: java, resultset

I am unable to store the `ResultSet` in an object array. I want to store it in an Object array and return it, how do I do this?

```
import java.sql.*;

public class TestSQLwithFunction {
    private static Object[] returnObjectArray() {
         String connnectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\FAISAL-
         FAS:1433;username=sa;password=password";
         Object ob[] = null;
         try {
             Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
             Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connnectionURL);
             ResultSet rs = conn.getMetaData().getSchemas();
             while(rs.next()) {
                 ob =  (Object[]) rs.getObject(1);
             }
         }
         catch(Exception e){
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         return ob;
    }


    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Object[] checkrs = returnObjectArray();
        for(int i = 0; i <= checkrs.length; i++){
            System.out.println(checkrs);
        }
    }
}
```

I get this exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   [Ljava.lang.Object; at
>   TestSQLwithFunction.returnObjectArray(TestSQLwithFunction.ja‌​va:13)
>   at TestSQLwithFunction.main(TestSQLwithFunction.java:24) Exception in
>   thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   TestSQLwithFunction.main(TestSQLwithFunction.java:25)

Comment: @Ezio is right...use his method...it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use object array but you can use collection API also.

Try this:

```
 private static ArrayList returnObjectArray()throws Exception {
     String connnectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\FAISAL-FAS:1433;username=sa;password=password";

        ArrayList<Object> data = new ArrayList();

     try {
         Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
         Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connnectionURL);
         ResultSet rs = conn.getMetaData().getSchemas();

         while(rs.next()) {
             data.add(rs.getObject(1));
         }
     }
     catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     return data;
}


public static void main (String[] args) {
    for(Object checkers: returnObjectArray()){
        System.out.println(checkers);
    }
}
```

I used `ArrayList`. You can make this more flexible if you want, Using key-value pair. To do this you can use `HashMap`, `HashTable` or you can create your own custom one.

If you want custom one:

1. create one class for key-value pair(lets say class name Pair).
2. in `Pair` class add two variable for key and value.
3. implement constructor: `Pair(String key, Object o){//..}`
4. then in the `returnObjectArray` initialize `ArrayList<Pair> data = new ArrayList();`
5. then add values as `data.add(new Pair("column name", rs.getObject(1)))`
6. then retrieve values using for-each loop.

Answer (score 2):

Create a java class representing the table that you have in SQL. Each member variables should represent each of the column of your SQL table. Then as you are traversing the row, create an object of the class passing all the data from the ResultSet to the constructor. This way you will store one row in one of the object. Keep doing this for all your rows and store the objects in some data structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(rs.next()) {
     ob =  (Object[]) rs.getObject(1);
}
```

`rs.getObject(1)` returns an Object, but you are trying to cast it to a `Object[]`

Comment: without this it is giving this compilation error                                                    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to Object[]

 at TestSQLwithFunction.returnObjectArray(TestSQLwithFunction.java:13)
 at TestSQLwithFunction.main(TestSQLwithFunction.java:24)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
int i=0;
while(rs.next()){
    ob[i]=rs.getObject(i+1);
    i++;
}
```